# No such key '...' in schema

Tags: updates, pantheon-terminal

Hi I have accidentally removed all `trusted.pgp` even directory with `trusted.pgp.d` in `/etc/apt/`. But I have restored with `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32` for example and try to add all key but when i try to upgrade, every thing seems good, but for some reason, some software return error like,

> No such key 'button-layout' in schema 'org.gnome.mutter:Pantheon' as
>   specified in override file
>   '/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/20_elementary.pantheon.wm.gschema.override';
>   ignoring override for this key.

There's another error that I don't take note of.

How can I fix this??

Comment: Have you used the tweaks app? I had changed a few settings that must have been deprecated by the eOS team. Removing the `button-layout` and `enable-animations` keys from the `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/20_elementary.pantheon.wm.gschema.override` got rid of the errors.